# I need help finding the complexity of an algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

i have the following algorithm :

j = 1
while j ≤ n do
j = 2^j

where n is our input and is a non negative integer

I found the complexity of the algorithm to be O(1) . Can someone tell me if this is correct and if not can you tell me the right answer and explain the way you found it? Thank you.

Comment: Without a problem solved by above *procedure*, there is no [algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/algorithms/info). Anyway, just execute it mentally, using pen&paper or any means giving you some visual impression, for values of, say, 42, 2022 and 8000000000 (approx. #live humans): does the effort change?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A014221. I think this might help.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 3):

The base-2 [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) function $\log^*(n)$ is the number of times you need to apply the logarithm function to obtain a value that is at most $1$.  It is a very slowly growing function.  The answer seems to be $O(\log^* n)$.

See [CLRS, Section 3.2, p. 58-59], which states that the number of atoms in the observable universe is about $10^{80}$, which is much smaller than $2^{65536}$ (whose iterated logarithm is $5$). Hence, for any practical input size $n$, your algorithm would have at most $5$ iterations, and so it is ok to take the running time of the algorithm to be $O(1)$.

Comment: Technically $O(1)$ still implies a behavior for $n$ to infinity. It is better to say that *the running time is bounded in practice*.

Answer (score 2):

No, the complexity cannot be constant, because the iterations $j = 2^j$ always yield a finite integer, and there is always a larger $n$. So the number of iterations is unbounded.

Anyway, as the required n grow astronomically fast (see below), the number of iterations grows extremely slowly.

The iterates are

$$1, 2, 4, 16, 65536, 2.0035299304\cdots\cdot 10^{19728},$$ and there is no way to write down the next value.